# MYSQL - Connect MYSQL Workbench to a MYSQL server on localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I know the question I am about to ask is a very stupid once but I am new to MYSQL so please bear with me. Want I want to do is create a database on my local machine and also access/manipulate it from their. I thought MYSQL WB was the all in one tool to do this i.e it will also allow me to create a database and also make a MYSQL server from which to access it. But I came to know the Workbench is just a front end and you need to have a some kind of a seperate MYSQL server module for it to access. 
The problem is I can't seem to find any link for a simple a server module on the MYSQL download site. 
  http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/ .

It has one Cluster Server but I don't think this is what I am looking for. If anyone could provide a link to the MYSQL server module using which I could connect MYSQL Workbench on my local host, and the steps to connect them that would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The one your looking for is named [MySQL Community Edition](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/). The current version is 5.6.14. Just select your platform (mac, linux or windows) and follow the [installation guide.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/installing.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to have php/mysql then you can download xampp. It includes all the necessary tools. Or if you wish to install it separately then follow this for Windows,

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/